how is 積み重ね connected to the sentence?

This song is called snowdrop, by Luna Haruna, and I don't understand the intention behind 積み重ね in the sentence. I understand that the feelings are piling up, but I don't see how the noun 積み重ね would reinforce this action, since it's not in its verb form

Sounds like you're probably familiar with て-form and how it can be used as "and" when connecting verb phrases. Turns out there's a second way to do that in more formal / poetic speech, and that's to use the verb stem directly.

Class 1: 行く -> 行き
Class 2: 食べる -> 食べ
Class 3: する -> し

As in:

遠い山を登り、青空と広がる大地を望み、やがて故郷に戻った

So 積み重ね, while it looks like the noun derived from the verb stem, is actually in a "tenseless" form, just like with て. So her thoughts/feelings are piling up and (despite that) she's continuing on (moving on).
